# load page into a div

Tags: jquery, jquery-load

When page load first time the page contents which are I load on Jquery.ready javascripts work perfect then when I use ajax to do some things and try to load page again javascript are not working on that second page which I try to load. I tried to solve this problem by using `live()` / `on()` methods but it didn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#grupyonetimarea").load("/Panel/MusteriSourcePages/mus_grup_add.aspx");
});

$('#btnekleme').live('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Panel/MusteriSource/mus_kisiadd.aspx/mus_kisi_kaydet",
        data: "{ad:'" + $.trim($("#txtalt_mus_adi").val()) + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        before: $("#btnekleme").hide(),
        success: function (msg) {
            if (msg.d == "ok") {
                $("#grupyonetimarea").load("/Panel/MusteriSourcePages/mus_grup_add.aspx");
            } else $("#loaded").html(msg.d).show(500);
        },
        error: function (x, e) {
            alert("The call to the server side failed. " + x.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`live` is deprecated so use `on()` delegated event.. delegate it to closest static parent.. ( this might not be the issue but its safe to use on() for future if incase you want to update your jquery in near future...)..here is the [link](http://jq4you.blogspot.com/2013/02/jquery-direct-and-delegate-on-event.html) if you want to read more about `on()`

```
 $(document).on('click','#btnekleme', function () {.. //using closest static parent element is preferred here than the document
```

and you can send data as object in ajax

```
var inputValue= $.trim($("#txtalt_mus_adi").val());
data: {ad:inputValue},
```

Comment: **I tried to solve this problem by using live() / on () methods but it didnt work.**

Comment: I did. Hence, I put the particular quote in comment. You must mention that you have delegated the content too.

Comment: yes .. thanks... i updated.. :).. i thought that will help him later if we trys to updated his jquery incase..:).. anyways thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Thank u very much for all answers. i did it in that way i just made a function which is  kontrolet() when i run that dunction it works good way which I want.

```
      $(document).on('click', '#btnekleme', function () {
                    $("#grupyonetimarea").load("/Panel/MusteriSourcePages/mus_grup_add.aspx");
                });

 function kontrolet() {
         $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "/Panel/MusteriSource/mus_kisiadd.aspx/mus_kisi_kaydet",
                            data: "{ad:'" + $.trim($("#txtalt_mus_adi").val()) + "'}",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            async: true,
                            cache: false,
                            before: $("#btnekleme").hide(),
                            success: function (msg) {
                                if (msg.d == "ok") {
                                    $("#grupyonetimarea").load("/Panel/MusteriSourcePages/mus_grup_add.aspx");
                                    alert("Kayıt işlemi başarılıdır.!");
                                    TextArealariClearET();
                                    $("#btnekleme").show();
                                }
                                else
                                    $("#loaded").html(msg.d).show(500);
                            },
                            error: function (x, e) {
                                alert("The call to the server side failed. " + x.responseText);
                            }
                        });
        }
```